# Simplify / Factorize after applying Chain & Quotient Rules

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Differentiate the below:
$$y = \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^3$$

By application of chain rule, and then quotient rule my answer is:
$$y'=\frac{3(x^2+1)^2(x^2+1)(2x)-(2x)(x^2-1)}{(x^2-1)^4}$$

The textbook answer is:
$$y'= \frac{(-12x)(x^2+1)^2}{(x^2-1)^4}$$

But how to get there? I can simplify my answer further, but hit a stopping point. What's next?
$$y'=\frac{(6x)(x^2+1)^3-(2x)(x^2-1)}{(x^2-1)^4}$$

Comment: $$x^2+1=x^2-1+2$$

Comment: You need to restart your application of the quotient rule, the term with the derivative of the denominator is wrong/incomplete. Or even better, use the third power as outer function and the quotient as inner function in the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there maybe a small typo in your answer. $$y =(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1})^3 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(x^2-1)^33(x^2+1)^2(2x)-(x^2+1)^33(x^2-1)^2(2x)}{(x^2-1)^6}$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{6x(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)-(x^2+1)^3(6x)}{(x^2-1)^4} = \frac{6x(x^2+1)^2[x^2-1-x^2-1]}{(x^2-1)^4} = \frac{(-12x)(x^2+1)^2}{(x^2-1)^4}$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution is very clear, but I'm having trouble following the cancellation that happened when the denominator moved from exponential order 6 to order 4 (between lines 1 and 2). If $(x^2-1)^6=(x^2-1)(x^2-1)(x^2-1)(x^2-1)(x^2-1)(x^2-1)$, we could simply cancel all of the similar terms out of the numerator completely?